# on adding targetSDKVersion app is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have a step counter Andriod app, I have to upload it on playstore and it's not working with targetSDKversion defined as playstore needs a API level 29+

and this default API is 28 (Playstore Console told)

[image]

this is the /build.gralde file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        if (rootProject.ext.has("gradle_classpath")) {
            classpath rootProject.ext.gradle_classpath
        } else {
            logger.warn('classpath not found in rootProject')
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{url "https://jitpack.io"}
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    if (rootProject.ext.has("compileSdkVersion")) {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    } else {
        logger.warn('compileSdkVersion not found in rootProject')
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.j4velin.pedometer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    flavorDimensions "main"

    productFlavors {
        fdroid {
            dimension "main"
        }
    }

    lintOptions{
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        disable 'ExtraTranslation'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
}

repositories {
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.j4velin.colorpicker:colorpicker:1.20.6'
    implementation 'com.github.j4velin.EazeGraph:EazeGraph:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.apps.dashclock:dashclock-api:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.Shashank02051997:FancyToast-Android:0.1.8'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'    
    playImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:17.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'

    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:2.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:2.0.0@aar'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is working and app is working fine and counting steps
but when I add targetSDKVersion

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.j4velin.pedometer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 30 //APP STOPS COUNTING STEPS
    }
```

This is my AndroidManifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.shubham.pedo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar"
        tools:replace="label">
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".PEDOMETER.Google_Sign_In"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <receiver android:name=".PEDOMETER.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".PEDOMETER.AppUpdatedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".PEDOMETER.SensorListener" />
        <service
            android:name=".PEDOMETER.widget.DashClock"
            android:permission="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.permission.READ_EXTENSION_DATA">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.Extension" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="protocolVersion"
                android:value="2" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="worldReadable"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="description"
                android:value="Displays the steps taken today" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".PEDOMETER.widget.WidgetConfig"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".PEDOMETER.widget.Widget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget" />
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".PEDOMETER.widget.WidgetUpdateService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Everything is working fine without adding targetSDKVersion, with adding this playstore accepts release apk but that stops counting the steps of User

Comment: You are advised to check whether all SDK versions are updated. Some earlier versions may have compatibility issues. And just to confirm, could you pls provide the crash log?then we can try to find out what can be wrong about it.

Comment: No crash, just counting of steps not working, I will post Logcat also in both cases

Comment: how to check about this all SDK versions?